# Null Pointer exception on new Mat() function of openCV

Tags: android, opencv, nullpointerexception, mat

In my app I got `NullPointerException` in the line:

```
Mat edges = new Mat();
```

I debug it, and come to here:

```
 public Mat() {
        nativeObj = n_Mat();
        return;
    }
```

On line of `nativeObj = n_Mat();` this . And got `NullPointerException`. So can anyone help to resolve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you calling return in a constructor?

Comment: @tolgap it's not his constructor actually...

Comment: Tell the truth this part isn't not my code , It's generated from openCV library for android, but I think empty return will not interrupt

Comment: That is a bit weird, are you sure it is that line? Maybe you should show us the log output so we inspect it.

Answer (score 0):

The null error generally occurs when you are declaring the variable before its library has been initialized.
Define it in your public class and then initialize it in the function public void onCameraViewStarted() 

Hope this helps.